# Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

There is a error in the Android Studio if the project is built:

The error in the Android Studio:

```
Gradle: Der Befehl "C:\Program" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':MyApplication:dexDebug'.
> Running C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.2.2\dx.bat failed. See output

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

The output in the command window for `gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace` is:

```
The TaskContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be remove
d in Gradle 2.0. Please use the create() method instead.
:MyApplication:prepareDebugDependencies
:MyApplication:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:MyApplication:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:MyApplication:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:MyApplication:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:MyApplication:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyApplication:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:MyApplication:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:MyApplication:compileDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 27.437 secs
```

The output for the command `gradlew clean build` is:

```
The TaskContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be remove
d in Gradle 2.0. Please use the create() method instead.
:MyApplication:clean
:MyApplication:prepareDebugDependencies
:MyApplication:compileDebugAidl
:MyApplication:generateDebugBuildConfig
:MyApplication:mergeDebugAssets
:MyApplication:compileDebugRenderscript
:MyApplication:mergeDebugResources
:MyApplication:processDebugManifest
:MyApplication:processDebugResources
:MyApplication:compileDebug
:MyApplication:dexDebug
Der Befehl "C:\Program" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
:MyApplication:dexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':MyApplication:dexDebug'.
> Running C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\
android-4.2.2\dx.bat failed. See output

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 33.459 secs

C:\Users\Michael\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplicationProject>
```

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't speak German but I know that error - you have a space in your path that's not escaped on Windows (C:\Program Files).

I've no idea where the space is or why you're triggering it (I've successfully used continuous integration on Windows to build Android Gradle projects and it worked just fine). Post your `build.gradle`, please.

Also, there's a quick and easy test - move everything to a path without spaces and try again.

Comment: Android Studio is installed in C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\, There are no spaces in the path

Comment: There *are* spaces in *some* path, for something that gets executed during dexing. What it is, I don't know. Have you customized your build.gradle?

Comment: At the moment I have another problem using the SDK manager, so I cannot investigate this problem further but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I had the very same problem. The problem came from the space in the path for the java executable in C:\Program Files[...].

I solved making a little modification at the end of the file [...]android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.2.2\dx.bat;
provided you already set JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME correctly, substitute the last line:

```
call  %java_exe% %javaOpts% -Djava.ext.dirs=%frameworkdir% -jar %jarpath% %params%
```

with this line:

```
call  java %javaOpts% -Djava.ext.dirs=%frameworkdir% -jar %jarpath% %params%
```

Comment: This answer is the correct answer. Can you explain what the difference between the two is so I know how I'm affecting my program?

Comment: Also, when opening AVD Manager in Android Studio I also get the `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command`...I'm sure this is related. Any fix for that?

Comment: Perhaps your java_exe env var is not defined but java is on the %PATH%.